# How do I create JSON object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var dates = [
                {
                    "marker": "1986", 
                    "type": "default",
                    "title": "Master of Puppets" ,
                    "content": "Metallica's third studio album, Master of Puppets, was recorded at Sweet Silence Studios and was released in March 1986. The album reached number 29 on the Billboard 200, and spent 72 weeks on the chart.[23] The album was the band's first to be certified gold on November 4, 1986, and was certified six times platinum in 2003.[24] Steve Huey of Allmusic considered the album \"the band's greatest achievement\".[25] Following the release of the album, Metallica supported Ozzy Osbourne for a United States tour.[21] Hetfield broke his wrist skateboarding down a hill and continued the tour performing vocals, with guitar technician John Marshall playing rhythm guitar.[26]"
                },
                {
                    "marker": "1991", 
                    "type": "youtube-video",
                    "title": "Ten" ,
                    "youtubeId": "VbhsYC4gKy4" ,
                    "content": "With the success of Ten, Pearl Jam became a key member of the Seattle grunge explosion."
                },
                {
                    "marker": "1992", 
                    "type": "image",
                    "title": "Nirvana",
                    "img": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Nirvana_around_1992.jpg",
                    "content": "Kurt Cobain (front) and Krist Novoselic (left) live at the 1992"
                },
                {
                    "marker": "1994", 
                    "type": "default",
                    "title": "5 de Abril" ,
                    "content":"<p>I am the best </p>"
                }
            ];
```

I have an object like this in my code ( to generate a timeline on my html page ) . How do I generate such an object dynamically?How do I assign content to these tags ( "marker","type") dynamically ?

Comment: read jquery documentation

Comment: `dates.push({marker: someVariableThatHoldsYourValue})`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object".

Comment: What if my content is in a php variable($value) which I am accessing through an AJAX request to a server side script? ...@Kolink @shift66

Comment: Sorry @Kolink ... I am new to these terminologies!

Answer (score 1):

To output any PHP variable in JSON format, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode).

Next time, ask the question you mean rather than making us coax it out of you in the comments, okay? ;)

Answer (score 0):

JSON stand for JavaScript Object Notation. In JavaScript, it is used to define javascript objetcs. A JavaScript Object build out of JSON is basically a collection of key:value pairs.

Since JavaScript is a prototype-based language ( see here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming ), you can "generate dynamically" this kind of object simply by assigning it wathever key:pair value you want. Example :

```
var RandomObject = {} //Create an empty key:pair values object
RandomObject["SomeKey"] = "SomeValue";
```

which will basically do the same thing as if you did this :

```
var RandomObject = {"SomeKey":"SomeValue"}
```

Now, what you have here is an array of key:value pairs. In order to recreate that dynamically, you would need to first create a JavaScript array, and then assign it your key:pair values :

```
var DynamicDates = new Array();
DynamicDates[0] = {
    "marker": "1991", 
    "type": "youtube-video",
    "title": "Ten" ,
    "youtubeId": "VbhsYC4gKy4" ,
    "content": "With the success of Ten, Pearl Jam became a key member of the Seattle grunge explosion."
};
```

Note : I picked the second entry to make it shorter in the example.